# Parallelization doubles the execution time

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to parallelize a loop with OpenMP but the result is that the user time spent (reported by /usr/bin/time) becomes twice as large compared to the unparallelized code. So the wall clock execution times of the parallelized and unparallelized code are approximately the same. Here is the code:

```
Real ComputeEPPMRMatrixElement7Opt4(
  UniformGrid3d const & ugLeft, ColumnVector const & vLeft,
  UniformGrid3d const & ugRight, ColumnVector const & vRight
  )
  {
  assert( ugLeft.si == ugRight.si );
  UniformGrid3d const ugInt = GridIntersection( ugLeft, ugRight );
  if( ! EmptyGrid( ugInt ) )
    {
    Real rSum = 0.0;
    Real const * const arLeft = vLeft.data( );
    Real const * const arRight = vRight.data( );
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:rSum)
    for( Integer nX = ugInt.tiMinX; nX <= ugInt.tiMaxX; nX++ )
      {
      for( Integer nY = ugInt.tiMinY; nY <= ugInt.tiMaxY; nY++ )
        {
        // We may do the following optimization because ugInt is the
        // intersection of the left and the right grids.
        // Actually it should be safe to remove the range checks from
        // the two following function calls.
        Integer const iLeft =
          ugLeft.GetVectorIndexWithCheck( nX, nY, ugInt.tiMinZ );
        Integer const iRight =
          ugRight.GetVectorIndexWithCheck( nX, nY, ugInt.tiMinZ );
        Real const * arLeft1 = &arLeft[ iLeft ];
        Real const * arRight1 = &arRight[ iRight ];
        for( Integer nZ = ugInt.tiMinZ; nZ <= ugInt.tiMaxZ; nZ++ )
          {
          Real const rLeft = *arLeft1++;
          Real const rRight = *arRight1++;
          rSum += rLeft * rRight;
          }
        }
      }
    Real const rScale = exp2( -3 * ugInt.si );
    return rScale * rSum;
    }
  else
    {
    return 0.0;
    }
  }
```

Note that Real is an alias for double. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the data you’re using to test your code? In general, parallelization has a high const cost

Comment: The code computes a matrix element as an integral of a product of two functions whose values are given in a three-dimensional point set.

Comment: What is the size of it? On small data set, parallelization is too costly to be efficient

Comment: Each of the three nested loops involves dozens or hundreds of elements.

Comment: What is the primary loop size?

Comment: I would say between 1 and 200.

Comment: I'll try to parallelize some outer loop. Lots of thanks for your help.

Comment: Then I’m afraid your problem is not worth a parallelization. Examples of problems that require it either have a very large sets of data to go through or have a costly treatment which is not your case.

Comment: How do you measure your times

Comment: I use /usr/bin/time for measuring times. I'm using Linux.